# variables scope in javascript D3

Tags: javascript, variables, d3.js

I have a problem with variables scope. In the code below, I have two  variables that i want to assign them some values and then later in the code use these values.
The variables are: eSVG, originMouse.
I assign their values when I am using mousedown event function and then trying to use these values in mousemove event function but i always get undefined values.
Could you please tell me what is happening here?

Thanks guys

```
var eSVG, originMouse;

svg.on("mousedown", function() {
     eSVG= this,  // svg element
     originMouse = d3.mouse(eSVG),  // mouse origing
     rect = svg.append("rect").attr("class", "zoom");
     originMouse[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, originMouse[0]));
     originMouse[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, originMouse[1]));
   })
.on("mousemove", function() {
    console.log(eSVG);                          **// undefined**
    var m = d3.mouse(eSVG);
    console.log(originMouse);                   **// undefined** 
    m[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, m[0]));
    m[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, m[1]));
    rect.attr("x", Math.min(originMouse[0], m[0])-130)
        .attr("y", Math.min(originMouse[1], m[1])-80)
        .attr("width", Math.abs(m[0] - originMouse[0]))
        .attr("height", Math.abs(m[1] - originMouse[1]));
  })
```

Comment: Are you sure `mousedown` is firing before `mousemove`?

Comment: it is a good question, i think thats the problem.. im gona give it a try
thanks Dogbert

Comment: yea sure thats the problem, thanks again Dogbert

Comment: post the code here afterwards and mark it as the valid answer. Also, @Dogbert should get some kudos for helping you out... +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what i did after I took Dogbert's comment in consideration:

```
 var eSVG, originMouse;

 svg.on("mousedown", function() {
 eSVG= this,  // svg element
 originMouse = d3.mouse(eSVG),  // mouse origing
 rect = svg.append("rect").attr("class", "zoom");
 originMouse[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, originMouse[0]));
 originMouse[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, originMouse[1]));

    svg.on("mousemove", function() {
        console.log(eSVG);                          **// defined **
        var m = d3.mouse(eSVG);
        console.log(originMouse);                   **// defined ** 
        m[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, m[0]));
        m[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, m[1]));
        rect.attr("x", Math.min(originMouse[0], m[0])-130)
           .attr("y", Math.min(originMouse[1], m[1])-80)
           .attr("width", Math.abs(m[0] - originMouse[0]))
           .attr("height", Math.abs(m[1] - originMouse[1]));
     })
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: i can accept my own answer in 2 days as stackoverflow site said.

Comment: exactly, forgot that detail! sorry! :)